# Looking For A Universal NFC tag that works with all NFC Phones

Tags: tags, nfc, universal

Hi I was wondering if there is a universal NFC tag that could be read by all NFC enabled devices. I have seen the following:

1. NTAG203
2. NTAG213
3. NTAG215
4. NTAG216

Would any NFC enabled device be able to read these? And what are the difference between the above tags and the following:

1. MiFair Classic
2. MiFair DESfire
3. MiFair Ultralight
4. MiFair Plus

Really just looking for a tag that can be read by all or the majority of NFC devices? Also could you please back up your answer. I would like to get an understanding as to why (if there is) a tag can be read by most devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're right NTAGxxx are standard NFC tags and develope to be compatible with all NFC devices:

http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf

> have been developed by NXP Semiconductors as standard NFC tag ICs to
>   be used in mass market applications such as retail, gaming and
>   consumer electronics, in combination with NFC devices or NFC compliant
>   Proximity Coupling Devices. NTAG213, NTAG215 and NTAG216 (from now on,
>   generally called NTAG21x) are designed to fully comply to NFC Forum
>   Type 2 Tag (Ref. 2) and ISO/IEC14443 Type A (Ref. 1) specifications.

- [MiFare Classic](http://www.nxp.com/products/identification-and-security/mifare-ics/mifare-classic:MC_41863?fsrch=1&sr=1&pageNum=1) : use a proprietary security protocol and required a NXP chip reader (or NFC chip reader with license) in NFC devices
- [MiFare DESfire](http://www.nxp.com/products/identification-and-security/mifare-ics/mifare-desfire:MC_53450) : use a proprietary security protocol, compatible with lot of NFC devices
- [MiFare Ultralight](http://www.nxp.com/products/identification-and-security/mifare-ics/mifare-ultralight:MC_53452?fsrch=1&sr=1&pageNum=1) : quite cheap, but with limited memory, compatible with lot of NFC devices
- [MiFare Plus](http://www.nxp.com/products/identification-and-security/mifare-ics/mifare-plus:MC_57609): new version of Mifare classic

Comment: @Chris Is it useful ?